# Как выбрать строку целиком?

Tags: регулярные-выражения

Как в регулярном выражении задать строку от начала до конца?

```
(\A(^\Z)*\Z)
```

начало строки, не конец строки , конец строки.
Но так не работает.

Comment: `^(\A(^\Z)*\Z)$`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`\A(^\Z)*\Z` означает "начало строки", ноль и более начал строки, за которым следует конец строки, а затем конец строки. Бессмыслица. Наверное, вы полагаете, что `^` в `(^\Z)` служит отрицанием, но это не так. Даже если вы используете отрицающий символьный класс и поместите в него `\Z` (т.е. `[^\Z]`), он не станет находить всё кроме конца строки, так как *символьные классы* используются для поиска *символов*, а не позиций в строке. Все такие специальные символы - `$`, `^`, `\z`, `\Z`, `\b` (граница слова) - перестают быть таковыми в символьных классах.

Чтобы найти строку целиком, нужно использовать

```
(?s)\A.*\z # PCRE, .NET, Java, RE2
(?s)\A.*\Z # Python re
^[^]*$     # JavaScript
(?m)\A.*\z # Onigmo (Ruby)
```

Где

- `(?s)` (в Onigmo `(?m)`) - модификатор, который изменяет поведение точки, которая теперь находит символ переноса строки
- `\A` - начало строки
- `\z` / `$` / `\Z` - конец строки.